# How to install fonts

Tags: fonts, windows, texniccenter, gfsneohellenic

I use MikTeX 2.8. I want to install the greek fonts "GFS neohellenic".
I open the MikTeX package manager, I type GFS neohellenic but nothing similar is found.

I downloaded the fonts from http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/pages/en_typefaces20th.html

I searched through the net for similar issues but nothing seem to be the proper one.

How can I get them to work on windows?

P.S.:I use TeXNiC CenteR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install the font on your computer (e.g. C:\windows\fonts) and compile the .tex file with xelatex. The following is an example..

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\setmainfont{GFS neohellenic}

\begin{document}

asdf hjkl

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer. I used the aforementioned code, however it's not working. I get ~400 errors. When I try to see what is wrong TXC opens a .mf file and I heve no idea what is going on, whatsoever...Let alone, it takes about to minutes to build it...

Comment: That's strange! I just compiled it on Texnic centre and it works. Have you configured texnic centre to work with xelatex? If not, see [here] (http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=731). Also, please compile the above code and paste the first few errors here.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. have you otherwise successfully compiled a _normal_ .tex file with standard font in Greek on Texnic centre? I have a feeling that texnic doesn't support UNICODE. I could suggest you texmaker.. it works like a charm!

Comment: I have been using the package kerkis with TXC or the default babel. Greek letters are indeed suported by TXC. The first build says XeTeX is required to compile that document. I see... I tried to build a new profile... I have a question: What am I supposed to write on "Command line arguments to pass to the compiler"?

Comment: You can just choose the first option, main file's full path, as long as you don't have made some unconventional changes to your file. The code is `%pm`

Comment: I have good and bad news...The good news are no error occurs and a pdf is produced...The bad news are that instead of letters I get boxes...I tried with \usepackage[english, greek]{babel}, \usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc} at first and \usepackage{xgreek} latter but nothing happened...

Comment: Ok. I got some sample greek text from the following site: http://www.tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2008-October/037263.html and I used their code too. The output was perfect with texmaker but was filled with garbage characters with texnic centre. I guess the trouble lies there.

Comment: I installed TeXMakeR;it really works! Why is this happening to TXC? Thank you very much for your time! I think I have to get used to TeXMakeR now...

Answer (score 5):

These are OpenType (OTF) fonts. Install them in your windows system font folder and use them with `xelatex/lualatex` + the `fontspec` package.

Comment: How am I going to do it? I don;t have xelatex/lualatex. I use LaTeX and TXC...

Comment: @Thanos: You have xelatex. It is part of miktex 2.8. Lualatex is in miktex 2.9.

Comment: I see...How am I going to use it? What am I suppossed to do to make it work?Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use it instead of latex. And if you search the site here you will find a lot example documents.