# Linux libertine font cannot be found

Tags: tables, xetex

I was trying to display IPA symbols using the font *Linux Libertine O* in xetex. However, the following error occured,

> Package fontspec Error: The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.

How to solve this issue. Code snippet is given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % use any font on your system that has the IPA symbols you need
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Vrinda}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=los,
    listname={List of Diagrams},
    name=Diagram,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=none,
]{diagram}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] % <--- "here", "top", "bottom"
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{Text Text Text Text}
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    \toprule
    \toprule
\makecell[lb]{Misspelled Word}
            & \makecell[b]{Correct Word}
                                & \makecell[b]{Translation in English}\\
    \midrule
\textbengali{পাহাড } (IPA: paɦaɖ) & \textbengali{পাহাড়}(IPA: paɦaɽ) & Mountain \\ % make sure you keep only the Bangla text (and not the IPA) within \textbengali{}
\textbengali{বিশেয}(IPA: biʃedʒ) & \textbengali{বিশেষ}(IPA: biʃeʃ) & Special \\
\textbengali{ফুটরল}(IPA: pʰuʈrɔl) & \textbengali{ফুটবল}(IPA: pʰuʈbɔl) & Football \\

    \bottomrule
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \label{table9}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you installed this font? What distribution of Linux you are using?

Comment: I am new in Latex. I am not using Linux, I am using Windows. I thought this is the font name I found in stackexchange. I don't know how to install a font in latex. I am using Miktex. Thank you

Comment: Did you have a look in here? [windows - How to install fonts - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49621/how-to-install-fonts).

Comment: I don't have the Vrinda font but beside this it compiles fine in miktex. The font used is in the miktex folder in `fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf`. Check if you have it. Is your miktex up-to-date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a font that you have on your computer (just as I had to download Vrinda to mine for your code). Linux Libertine O is available for [free download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/), as are the others I mentioned in my answer to your original question. If you have Microsoft products on your computer, you may have some fonts that have a few IPA symbols (Calibri, Cambria, Times New Roman, etc.), but they might not work well with diacritic stacking or overbars.

There's no IPA font that is perfect in every respect (e.g., Linux Libertine O is missing a few superscript IPA characters and has clashing overbars, Charis SIL doesn't have ligatures or true small caps, Gentium doesn't have ligatures or true bold or true small caps). See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304297/42880) and [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249260/42880) for more discussion.

You can also use `\usepackage{libertine}` to get Linux Libertine O but that doesn't generalize to other IPA fonts like the `\setmainfont` with a system font does.

Answer (score 2):

I remember having similar problems, trying to remove the "O" (don't think that helped), etc.

What I ended up doing was using the **Libertinus** fonts (a fork of the Libertine fonts). You can find them [here](https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus).

After installing them in `~/.fonts` and running `fc-cache -f -v`, and making sure you're using LuaTeX or XeTeX, you can put something like

```
\setmainfont[
Ligatures=TeX
]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setsansfont[
Ligatures=TeX
]{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont[
Ligatures=TeX,
Scale=0.95
]{Libertinus Mono}
```

In your preamble/style file.